# How to use svgpanzoom in a nodejs application

Tags: svg, electron, svg.js, svgpanzoom

I'm tring to use [svg.panzoom.js](https://github.com/svgdotjs/) 2.0.2 into a Electron app but I'm wronging something that, I think, is about how I include the plugin into the app. This is my html

```
<div id="drawing"></div>
```

Then in my ***index.js*** file

```
    require('@svgdotjs/svg.panzoom.js');
...
    var draw = SVG('drawing')
                 .size(900, 300)
                 .panZoom();
```

But PanZoom is not recognized as a function of SVG.
Any idea?

Comment: Are you using svg.js v3? If so, the correct way to create an SVG is `SVG().addTo('#drawing')...` and you need to setup a viewbox: `viewbox(0,0,900,300)`

Comment: No @Fuzzyma is the 2.6.2 that I got by npm

Comment: In that case you should also load a corresponding version of panzoom: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg.panzoom.js - it is loaded with require(`svg.panzoom.js`). The bit about the viewbox still holds true!

Comment: @Fuzzyma excuse me the dummy question but how can I understand which vers goes ?

Comment: the one which is installed when you do `npm i svg.panzoom.js` + I linked to the version which works